# Reset all Google Chrome settings on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

I enabled some experimental features in Chrome (using the `about:flags` page), and I'm trying to reinstall it completely (since it has begun to malfunction in various ways - for example, flash applets and extensions are no longer working.) Is there any way to completely reset Google Chrome on Ubuntu, so that all default settings are restored?

Comment: In general, what process should be followed for completely reinstalling an application on Ubuntu?

Comment: I found a duplicate question, but it doesn't have any useful answers yet: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225811/how-to-reinstall-google-chrome

Comment: you might also go to Settings, create and edit a new user, than delete the old one (http://askubuntu.com/a/231014/47206)

Comment: Another duplicate (which actually solved my problem!): http://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium

Comment: maybe resetting settings is not a duplicate of reinstalling, although the user agreed to reinstalling

Comment: By the way, people may like to "star" this bug which asks for a convenient way to reset `about-flags`: [ Issue 139307: Provide a way to reset all chrome://flags/ to factory settings](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139307).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general answer to that can be found in the link below, this should be closed as duplicate.

[What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Basically

```
apt-get purge package
apt-get install package
```

Comment: For the command `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome`, I got the following error: `Virtual packages like 'google-chrome' can't be removed`.

Comment: have you tried to use the auto-completion? In my case I have to say `apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`. I assume you are using [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome) ppa. There is no package called google-chrome

Comment: I ran the command `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`, and then reinstalled Chrome, but all of my settings were still the same after reinstallation. What I really need to do is to remove all the configuration files for Google Chrome, since they were apparently not removed.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, as (I) mentioned in the answer to the question linked here, it won't remove any user-level configuration changes. See the [other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/251430/88802) of cipricus - that should work.

Comment: @gertvdijk you're right, I misinterpreted the question. [at]AndersonGreen it would be helpful for later visitors if you could change the accepted question from mine to the answer of cipricus, which, together with the comment of gertvdijk, would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 4):

I think this works without removing all the program. Create new profile (User) like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/231014/47206).

Than delete the old/default one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, remove `/home/username/.config/google-chrome` recursively (e.g. `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome`) to remove *all* of the configuration files. (in case Chrome isn't even starting up anymore to perform the steps in the answer)

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.config/chromium` for fixing chromium! Chromium just keep loading on Ubuntu after sync up with google account. This command save my ass.

Answer (score 0):

That was interesting!   After a routine updating in Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome would only try to start showing the first window, and after a few seconds would just disappear.
I opened xfe in superuser mode (sudo xfe) and I went to the home/user/.config and searched for the file corresponding to google, (google-chrome).  Changed the name of that file, (just in case I needed it again), and magically, now Chrome has no problem running. Chrome managed to reconstruct the google-chrome, end even kept my bookmarks, etc.