# I keep getting logged out of Chrome

Tags: login, google-chrome, gnome-keyring

I keep getting logged out of my chrome account, getting the message "A change in your account requires you to sign in" every time. This happens any time I log out of Ubuntu and back in again.

I know the problem is not with my Google account because I have taken the following steps:

- Deleted the account and purged chrome from my computer
- Deleted my server side account and relinked it
- Opened a new google account (I have the same problem)

However, the one thing that did fix the problem was to create a new user account on my computer and log into my chrome from that account. I was able to log out and then log back in to my Ubuntu account and it worked.

I have concluded that the problem is something specific to my account.

I deleted my keyring, but that does not appear to have fixed the issue. Does any one have any ideas?

(By the way, this question is similiar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823874/always-logged-out-from-chrome), but I have done far more research steps, so I am posting separately.)

Finally, I copied and pasted my `/home/kg` folder to a new user, which seems to work. However, I would still like to fix it on my original account.

Comment: The problem is with the initial Chrome user profile. Uninstalling doesn't remoe user settings. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251410/reset-all-google-chrome-settings-on-ubuntu/251430#251430

Comment: @CelticWarrior I tried that already.

I also tried copying my `/home/kg` folder to a new account and it works fine there.