# How to install Iceweasel?

Tags: software-installation, iceweasel

I was [searching for Firefox-like browsers ('clones')](https://askubuntu.com/q/228309/47206) and [found about a few](https://askubuntu.com/a/231014/47206) that I want to test, but could not install Iceweasel in Ubuntu. (Older links that I found with this google search  - [here](http://namakutux.blogspot.com/2012/07/install-iceweasel-10-esr-on-ubuntu-1204.html) and [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/install-iceweasel-web-browser-in-debian-and-ubuntu.html) - are outdated/dead.)

Is it possible? Where to download the package from?

---

In fact finding the package is enough for me - I think that, [just like Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/a/283201/47206), [Swiftweasel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftweasel/files/Swiftweasel%20Trunk%20%28Unstable%29/3.5%20RC3%20%28tar.gz%29/) and [Seamonkey](https://askubuntu.com/a/45954/47206), these kind of browsers are able to run very well as 'portable' (just running the executable in the package folder).

---

I was searching for this browser to use it as another 'Firefox clone' (in the sense described in the linked question, like **Icecat**). But it seems that **Iceweasel** may refer to **two different projects**. One is the [former name of GNU Icecat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_IceCat), the other is a [Debian project](http://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel#How_to_install_Iceweasel_.28Firefox.29). More [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73748/32012). When I asked the question, this difference was not clear to me, and Icecat was already running on my computer. So, I wonder **if Iceweasel Debian version has its place on Ubuntu or not**.

Comment: ¿http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/iceweasel?

Comment: @carnendil - could you elaborate an answer based on the link you provided and Mitch's answer below? the packages indicated in that answer (with links that do not work) are not exactly those from your link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since mixing Debian and Ubuntu [is not generally recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/116266/58950), I've tried (and succeded) to do it manually.

The Iceweasel package details page (http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/iceweasel) has links to download pages for different architectures, as well as a list of dependencies and suggested packages.

In my case, I go to the [i386 architecture](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/iceweasel/download) download page, where there are links to download the file from different mirrors. You can simply click on one of the links or copy it to run from a terminal:

```
wget -c http://ftp.mx.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iceweasel/iceweasel_3.5.16-20_i386.deb
```

Before installing the downloaded package, you need to make sure you have all dependencies installed. Any of the [solutions provided here](https://askubuntu.com/q/15452/58950) will do.

In my particular case, I had to download and install `xulrunner-1.9.1` and several of its dependencies: `libhunspell-1.2-0`, `libjpeg62`, and `libmozjs2d`. Each can be found at the link provided with the dependencies list.

Then, install everything (I show separated commands to reduce lenght of example):

```
sudo dpkg -i libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.11-1_i386.deb libjpeg62_6b1-1_i386.deb libmozjs2d_1.9.1.16-20_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i xulrunner-1.9.1_1.9.1.16-20_i386.deb iceweasel_3.5.16-20_i386.deb
```

**NOTE**: **Iceweasel "takes over" your current firefox configuration, and you will not be able to run both Iceweasel and Firefox at the same time**. Note the creation of the symbolic link `firefox.real` during installation (it links to `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh`):

[image: installation of iceweasel .deb package]

<sup>Click for a full-resolution version.</sup>

On first run, it will check and install (or reject) the add-ons from your Firefox:

[image: iceweasel add-on compatibility testing]

<sup>Click for a full-resolution version.</sup>

And this is Iceweasel up and running on my Ubuntu 12.04:

[image: iceweasel first run]

<sup>Click for a full-resolution version.</sup>

Comment: thank you for underlying that it "takes over" the current firefox configuration, and will not be able to run with Firefox at the same time. (this is a very good answer, although it disqualifies iceweasel as answer to the other question)

Answer (score 4):

> Iceweasel is a rebranding of Mozilla Firefox. It is essentially
>   Firefox but without the non-free components such as images and
>   plug-ins. The rebranding is currently taking place as two independent
>   projects. One is part of the Gnuzilla project, a GNU project to
>   provide versions of Mozilla programs using entirely free software. The
>   other is a rebranded build prepared by Debian. The two projects might
>   merge in the future.
>
> Warning: Please be advised if you have a bug in Iceweasel, because it
>   is not provided by a supported Ubuntu repository, the Ubuntu project
>   is unable to provide support or a fix. If you want support, you may
>   want to use firefox.<sup>1</sup>

Installation

First, install its dependency from the Ubuntu repository :

```
libnspr4-0d
```

Then, you need to download and install them manually :

```
xulrunner-10.0
libmozjs10d
iceweasel
```

Or, the simple way is by install them at once by

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

then fix its dependency by command :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Here is were you can get the files mentioned above.

(The previous link is dead)
To get Iceweasel click [Here](http://gnuzilla.gnu.org/download)

[libmozjs10d_10.0.5esr-2_i386.deb](http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/debian-main-i386/libmozjs10d_10.0.12esr-1_i386.deb.html)

[xulrunner-10.0_10.0.5esr-2_i386.deb](http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/debian-main-i386/xulrunner-10.0_10.0.12esr-1_i386.deb.html)

Also take a look [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=270631), and [Here](http://www.geticeweasel.org/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Install Iceweasel](http://namakutux.blogspot.com/2012/07/install-iceweasel-10-esr-on-ubuntu-1204.html)</sup>

Comment: (i'll delete all my comments here in the end) - but you posted a link to `icecat` for iceweasel: i am curious about the later package while `icecat` is well and running :) - please dont ask me why i need iceweasel when i have icecat :)

Comment: the iceweasel deb i found was this: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/iceweasel/iceweasel_3.5.16-20_i386.deb. i have installed `libnspr4-0d`. `xulruner`  requires `libmiszj`, which requires libffi5 >= 3.0.4  while i already have libffi6 v.3.0.11

Comment: `icecat` can be installed with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuzilla-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install icecat -y`

Comment: there seem to be two different uses of the name ***Iceweasel***. One is the [former name of GNU Icecat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_IceCat), the other is a [Debian project](http://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel#How_to_install_Iceweasel_.28Firefox.29). I've created a separate [question on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73748/32012).

Answer (score 1):

GNU IceCat and IceWeasel are essentially the same thing. IceCat and IceWeasel are simply rebranded as to become entirely free and open-source versions of Firefox.
If you would like to install it, refer here.

http://namakutux.blogspot.in/2012/07/install-iceweasel-10-esr-on-ubuntu-1204.html